# How delay ajax call by few seconds

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm not sure this is the best way to send 2 ajax togheter for facebook api.
But it works, the problem is that sometimes i get the second ajax (result_flow.php) before the first (result.php)
Will be helpful delay second ajax (url:result_flow.php) for 3 seconds or change this code in someway to give a order.

I tried setTimeout but didn't work.

```
$('#sub').click(function () {
    var data = $("input#dataInput").val();
    console.log(data);
    var total = $("input#totalInput").val();
    var subscriber_id = $("input#subscriber_id").val();
    var res_name = $("input#res_name").val();
    var dataString = 'data='+ data + '&total=' + total + '&subscriber_id=' + subscriber_id+ '&res_name=' + res_name;
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "result.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
           if(data==='success'){
               //localStorage.clear();
                   MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                       console.log("Webview closing");
                   }, function error(err) {
                       console.log(err);
                   });
                            }
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "result_flow.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(data);
           if(data==='success'){
                            }
        },3000);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Don’t use arbitrary timeouts, put the second AJAX call into the success handler of the first one instead.

Comment: If you need them in a specific order, you should call them in that order. Never trust that requests always will take the same amount of time. So having a timer might work in most cases but it could also backfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `setTimeout()` is not working because you put it inside the callback, which means it will be executed when the request is already done. Anyway that's not a proper way to handle such a task, you should put the second request inside the first's callback, so that it will be executed as the first one finishes.
The code looks like this:

```
$('#sub').click(function() {
    var data = $("input#dataInput").val();
    console.log(data);
    var total = $("input#totalInput").val();
    var subscriber_id = $("input#subscriber_id").val();
    var res_name = $("input#res_name").val();
    var dataString = 'data=' + data + '&total=' + total + '&subscriber_id=' + subscriber_id + '&res_name=' + res_name;
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "result.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data === 'success') {
                //localStorage.clear();
                MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
                    console.log("Webview closing");
                }, function error(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "result_flow.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }   
                });
            }      
        }
    });
}
```

Note that in my code the second request is sent just if the first one is successful because it's placed within the `if (data === 'success') {...}` statement.

Comment: avoid the "callback hell", there are better ways to solve this nowadays

Comment: @luschn Yep but this is the simplest solution for such a simple task with just two requests.

Comment: i would still never fall back to the callback hell, later you may need to add another callback in the second callback, who knows. also, async/await is much simpler even for only 2 callback levels.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use async/await nowadays, it is quite easy to use AJAX calls sequencially:

```
$('#sub').click(async () => {
    ...
    try {
        let data = await $.post({
            url: "result.php",
            data: dataString
        });
        if (data === 'success') {
            ...
        }
        data = await $.post({
            url: "result_flow.php",
            data: dataString
        });
        if (data === 'success') {
            ...
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

Not tested, as i don´t work with jQuery - but it should give you the idea. Since `$.ajax/$.post` supports Promises, it should work with async/await. Be aware that you may need to transpile your code with Babel for older browsers, but i suggest using Babel anyway.

**If you want to use both AJAX calls in parallel, use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (because they do not depend on each other) - the results will be in order, so you can make sure the callback code is called in order.**

Answer (score 0):

You should call them in chain. *Success... then...* using promise is the best way.

**Never trust the order you receive if is not explicitly written by you.**

[JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```html
Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() 
callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), 
and jqXHR.always() instead.
```

You can do something like this:

```js
// First Ajax call
$.ajax({
  // Do the request
  // Remove success to use new promise
})
.done(function( data ) {
    // Add the success here
    // Add the Second Ajax call here or create a function to call it, whatever you want
});
```